# How to create arrays with different names in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables

I'm currently working on a game (console application) with 25 Chunks, that are 5x5. All Chunks are in a List(5x5) witch is the Level in the end.
I do not want to declare all arrays. I would like to write a method in witch the arrays will be declared but with changing names.
For example: 
- ac_Array_1 
- ac_Array_2

```
    static void Level()
    {
        List<char[,]> ol_Level = new List<char[,]>();

    }
    static void Spielblock()
    {
        int i_Stelle = 1;
        string s_ArrayName = "ac_Chunk_" + i_Stelle;
        i_Stelle++;
        char[,] /*NAME*/ = new char[5, 5];
    }
```

Comment: You can use a Dictionary<string, char[,]> where in the key you set a name for your level and in the value you add the appropriate array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a dynamic variable name like you are requesting is not a simple thing to accomplish.

Generally, variable names are known at compile time, and the compiler can make optimizations using that information. What you are requesting would keep that from happening.

So the suggestions that you are seeing: create a variable, such as a dictionary, known when compiling and writing the code. Make that variable one that can dynamically expand to contain as many "chunks" as you'd like. And with a `Dictionary<string, char[,]>` you can even give each of those chunks a name. They won't be individual variable names, but it will let you access them by string/name and iterate through the collection in different ways.

To add a detail to Johnny's answer, at any point you can use

```
var ac_chunk = ol_Level["ac_Chunk_1"];
```

if you want to repeatedly access an individual chunk.

Or, even easier, just keep using `ol_Level[$"ac_Chunk_{chunkNumber}"]`

Comment: Oh now I see the problem. The whole time I thought with the Directory class I would create dynamic variables. What I am demanding is not possible if I understand it correctly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
int numOfLevels = 5;

Dictionary<string, char[,]> ol_Level = Enumerable
    .Range(1, numOfLevels)
    .ToDictionary(k => $"ac_Chunk_{k}", v => new char[5,5]);

ac_Chunk = ol_Level["ac_Chunk_1"];//char[5,5]

for (int i_Row = 0; i_Row < ac_Chunk.getLength(0); i_Row++) 
{ 
    for (int i_column = 0; i_column < ac_Chunk.getLength(1); i_column++) 
    { 
        ac_Chunk[i_Row, i_column] = '#'; 
    } 
} 

...
```

levels:

```
ac_Chunk_1, ac_Chunk_2, ac_Chunk_3, ac_Chunk_4, ac_Chunk_5
```

---

*n.b. using System.Linq and c# 6.0 $ interpolation*

Comment: I can only use the arrays within the Dictionary? Is this like a List or do I need to do it differently?

Comment: @escribe I updated the answer, is it clear how to access the level? It is key value pair collection, so it pair each level name with char[5,5]...

Comment: I dont understand it. I want to access the arrays and set values to them. Not declare a new varibale. I don't know how to access the arrays, it would be very kind of you to explain it to me.
For example:
for (int i_Row = 0; i_Row < ac_chunk.getLength(0); i_Row++)
{    for (int i_column =0; i_column < ac_chunk.getLength(1); i_column++)
     {    ac_chunk[i_Row, i_column] = '#'; } }

Comment: @escribe That logic doesn't change, once you have chunk you can apply that logic. However I update the answer...

Comment: Tahnks, but the problem that ac_Chunk does not exist and so I cannot debug, because there are still errors (CS0103)